Formation of Grignard reagent from alkyl halide

This question was asked in JEE exam, the correct answer given in option (D). Why doesn't the R-MgX formed, on one of the carbon, essentially C⁻, does nucleophilic substitution on the C-Br in the same molecule?

First: its halide not hallide, edit! Second, I do not get your question, if you have an excess of Grignard reagents, I would expect that both Br would be substituted. You say that the 4th answer is the right one, so... what is the problem here?
The reaction just happens twice, consuming two equivalents of Grignard reagent.

Do the two Bromine atoms get substituted simultaneously? If not then there is must be a possibility of attack on R-Br which is not substituted (in the same molecule) by R-MgX.

Sorry but I continue to have some difficulty understanding your doubt: there are so many Et-MgX molecules in the reaction enviroment to guarantee that the first of the two bromines is substituted, (first reaction), then the second one is substituted (second reaction). In the end you get a doubly substituted product.

Ok, I'm stupid, it says in the first step

It must be an error of whoever wrote the question, the first step should be a single substitution.

Grignard reagents are formed by a free-radical mechanism, so you should have a monosubstitution at first, not a concerted disubstitution. As for the intramolecular reaction you suggest; how feasible it is for a 3-membered ring (highly strained) to be formed from such an intramolecular cyclization is debatable. I would say not very feasible. A possible side reaction? Sure.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25001/grignard-formation-and-vicinal-dihalides https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/153472/can-a-grignard-reagent-form-magnesium-halide-with-an-alkyl-halide
